# how to Terminate ruing app from a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build a flutter app that terminate an app by my flutter app.I don't know how to do this can you give me some idea for this ?

Comment: You can't terminate apps in Flutter, you'll have to do it natively and I doubt you can terminate iOS apps and even Android nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the architecture of the modern mobile operation systems, memory access to other spaces is limited. That means, that you can't control other processes than created by you (your app in this case), so there is no way you can close other app, unless you have administrator privileges on the device

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using Flutter, and I can't even think you can do it natively, to terminate other apps you need OS privileges which you cannot get using Flutter